# Why am I getting "Indent expected" error in python 3.9.4?

Tags: python, python-3.9

I keep getting this error in python. It keeps saying Indent expected. Can you try to explain?

```
import pyautogui

def Bot():
    #Next_Wave = x=1782, y=1017
    #Get_Questions = x=988, y=646
    #Anwser = x=1128, y=706
```

Comment: You need to have some code in the function. If you want it to do nothing right now as a placeholder, you could use the `pass` keyword.

Comment: lol bruh moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comments are totally ignored here.
This is basically what you're doing

```
import pyautogui

def Bot():
```

Instead insert pass

```
import pyautogui

def Bot():
    pass
```

Comment: No problem ! give it a check if it helped you